# Google Fusion Tables cvs upload encoding problem

Tags: encoding, csv

I'm trying to import a large dataset into Google Fusion Tables using the csv-import function. The data contains Danish æ-ø-å characters. The original encoding of the data seems to be ANSI (or "windows-1252"). Data uploadet in that encoding is not displayed correctly. I've tried to reencode the various strings in most other relevant encodings (Encoding.(Unicode|ASCII|UTF8) etc.) but nothing seems to please Fusion Tables.

I'm using FileHelpers to generate the csv and I have tried explicitly setting the encoding there too, but to no avail.

Comment: I guess you have used importrow API for importing your csv in fusion table . Can you please get us  sample code snippet to import csv in fusion table in java

Answer (score 1):

UTF 8 should work. I had uploaded this table as a test: http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=276537